# How to insert into NatTable cell two texts (each with a different font) and one image? and set the margins?

Tags: java, html, css, nattable

Two questions:

1) How to insert into NatTable cell two text (each with a different font) and a image?

2) how to set the margins as the below image?

In the following cases:

a) Using java 1.6 (no RichTexCellEditor, no css).
b) Using java 1.7 (with RichTexCellEditor, no css).
c) Using java 1.8 (with RichTexCellEditor, with css).

[image: Image example]

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. NatTable styling is based on styles and painters as explained in [1]. For further information on NatTable configuration and getting started with NatTable, have a look at our Getting Started Tutorial [2]
2. To create a combination like the asked one, a combination of `ICellPainter` needs to be registered.
3. To add padding (not margin) between the cell border and the content, use the `PaddingDecorator`
4. To add an image additional to text, use a `CellPainterDecorator` that has a painter for the text as base and a `ImagePainter` as decorator.
5. Rendering text with different fonts is only supported by the `RichTextCellPainter` of the NatTable Nebula Extension. That one requires Java 1.7.
6. CSS styling in NatTable is used to create a styling configuration via CSS. There is no additional support despite that. The CSS support is contained in the NatTable E4 Extension that requires Java 1.8. The explanation is available in the 1.4 New & Noteworthy page [3]

So the answer to a) is: Rendering of text with two different fonts is not supported by NatTable Core, therefore you need to implement a custom `ICellPainter` that would support that.

The answer to b) is to create a complex painter and register it like this:

```
configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
    CellConfigAttributes.CELL_PAINTER,
    new BackgroundPainter(
            new PaddingDecorator(
                    new CellPainterDecorator(
                            new PaddingDecorator(new RichTextCellPainter(), 10, 0, 0, 0), 
                            CellEdgeEnum.LEFT, 
                            new ImagePainter()),
                    2, 5, 2, 5)),
    DisplayMode.NORMAL,
    ColumnLabelAccumulator.COLUMN_LABEL_PREFIX + 0);
```

Where the above example implies that there are column labels applied by the `ColumnLabelAccumulator` and the painter should only be configured for the first column. Also note that the style for that concrete cell would need the attribute `CellStyleAttributes.IMAGE` set, which is then be rendered by the `ImagePainter`. If the image should be fixed, it needs to be set as constructor parameter.

Of course the content needs to contain the necessary HTML markup for rendering different fonts. Something like:

```
<p><strong><span style="font-size:14px">This is a test</span></strong></p>
<p><span style="color:rgb(128, 128, 128)"><span style="font-size:12px">This is a test</span></span></p>
```

The answer to c) is not that trivial. First the complex painter structure shown above can't be accomplished with CSS. The reason is that multiple paddings need to be configured, which is not supported by the NatTable CSS.
Second the RichTextPainter is not known to the E4 Extension. Therefore it needs to be registered manually to the `CellPainterFactory`, e.g.

```
CellPainterFactory.getInstance().registerContentPainter(
    "richtext",
    (painterProperties, underlying) -> {
        return new RichTextCellPainter();
    });
```

where the handling of additional attributes need to be considered somehow.

In the CSS it would then look somehow like this:

```
painter: background padding decorator richtext;
decoration: left url('./nebula_logo_16.png') 5 true;
padding: 2 5;
```

[1] https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=styling
[2] http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html
[3] https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/nandn/nandn_140.php

Comment: How to center text in a RichTextCellPainter horizontally and / or vertically without using padding? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set appropriate values for the alignment style properties. Should be shown in the linked documentation and can be seen in the examples.